# Python OOP - How do I break out of an inherited (super) method based on the parent method?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, inheritance

In the base class, I want to test for something, and if not True, I want to avoid whatever processing would otherwise take place in the child class' method.

For instance, in this contrive example, if `some_thing` isn't provided, it is set to `None` in `__init__()`. Because its value is None, in the base class `add_some_thing()` method, I want to return the string "Nothing". But this doesn't prevent the child class' `add_some_thing()` method from continuing on. How can I achieve this?

I will have multiple classes inheriting from `BaseQuery`, or I would just move the `if not self.some_thing...` functionality to the child class. I'm trying not to repeat code a dozen times.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class BaseQuery(ABC):

    def __init__(
        self,
        some_thing=None,
    ):
        self.some_thing = some_thing
        super().__init__()

    @abstractmethod
    def add_some_thing(self):
        if not self.some_thing:
            return "Nothing"


class SpecificQuery(BaseQuery):

    def add_some_thing(self):
        super().add_some_thing()

        return self.some_thing
```

What I'm getting:

```
>>> t = SpecificQuery()
>>> print(t.add_some_thing())
None

>>> t = SpecificQuery(some_thing="Whatever")
>>> print(t.add_some_thing())
Whatever
```

What I want:

```
>>> t = SpecificQuery()
>>> print(t.add_some_thing())
Nothing

>>> t = SpecificQuery(some_thing="Whatever")
>>> print(t.add_some_thing())
Whatever
```

I guess the true question is this: How so I make a method in a child class respect the return value of the parent class, if a return value is provided?

---

Edit: Based on Frank's answer, managed to get it working. Here's the final product in case anyone else is looking for similar information:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class BaseQuery(ABC):

    def __init__(
        self,
        some_thing=None,
    ):
        self.some_thing = some_thing
        super().__init__()

    def add_some_thing(self):
        if not self.some_thing:
            return "Nothing"
        else:
            return self._add_some_thing()

    @abstractmethod
    def _add_some_thing(self):
        return


class SpecificQuery(BaseQuery):

    def _add_some_thing(self):
        super()._add_some_thing()

        return self.some_thing
```

What I'm getting now:

```
>>> t = SpecificQuery()
>>> print(t.add_some_thing())
Nothing

>>> t = SpecificQuery(some_thing="Whatever")
>>> print(t.add_some_thing())
Whatever
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclasses override base classes, not the other way around.

However there is a solution.  Typically, this is implemented by having a helper method `_add_some_thing`.  The underscore in the name of the helper method hints that this is a protected method and should only be used by subclasses.

The only implementation of `add_some_thing()` is in the base class.  It does or doesn't call `_add_some_thing()` depending on whatever criteria it wants.  Classes implement and override `_add_some_thing()`.

Comment: Thanks, @frank-yellin. This helped me a lot with understanding how to approach such problems. I think I've almost got it. Only issue now is that I have to use two sets of parenthesis to get the return value `t.add_some_thing()()`. Any recommendations on where I'm going wrong? Updated bottom of question to show what I did and what I'm getting out now.

Comment: Never mind. Figured it out. I'm returning `self._add_some_thing` instead of `self._add_some_thing()`. Thanks again!